# Git and Github - creating a branch on a fork

Tags: git, version-control, github, fork

I apologize if this is slightly open ended.  What I'd like to do is simple.  I've forked a repo on Github (SSH) that I'm working on.  If I clone my fork and create a new branch on it, will the new branch carry over to the original repo?  If not, is there a procedure for this?

I understand to keep track of the original repo, I have to add the `upstream` remote via `git remote add upstream`.  Will this also transfer branches added to my fork and any commits to the newly created branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep track of the original repo, your repo will get updated when the original repo does, but forking means you develop your own separate project and your changes won't affect the original repo. Actually, basically, cloning a repo requires only read-access, so you can fork a repo without even being able to write to it.

I assume "keeping track" results in rebasing your changes on top of the updated original repo master/branch, but anyway, it shouldn't have any effect on the original repo (specially if you access it without write-access, which makes it 100% safe).